# How to Map an object contains other object

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given the Source class as defined below:

```
class Source{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    Phone phone
    // getters and setters
}
```

and the Phone class as defined below:

```
class Phone{
        private Long id;
        private String phoneNumber;
        // getters and setters
    }
```

and the Target class as defined below:

```
class Target{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Long phone;
    // getters and setters
}
```

I have an interface :

```
@Mapper
interface MyMapper{
    @Mapping(source = "phone.id", target = "phone")
    Target toTarget(Source source);
    @Mapping(source = "phone", target = "phone.id")
    Source toSource(Target target);
}
```

How can change generated code to eliminate Phone object when id is null,

generated code;

```
source.setPhone(target t){
  if(t==null){
     return null;
  }
Phone f=new Phone();
if(t.getPhone!=null){
    f.setId(t.getPhone();
}
return f;
//in this case mapstruct create an object, even if the source is null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible within MapStruct. There is an already a feature request for something like this (see [#1166](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1166)).

The only way to achieve this would be to use `@AfterMapping` and set your phone to `null` if the id is `null`.

You can use `@AfterMapping` in the following way:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    Source map(Target target);

    @AfterMapping
    void afterMapping(@MappingTarget Source source) {
        if (source.getPhone() != null && source.getPhone().getId() == null) {
            source.setPhone(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Filip, how I can use this annotation, can you get me an example

Comment: I just updated my answer. In any case you can always find examples in the [Customizing mappings](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) section of the documentation